# Authorization using Api gateway and Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, serverless

Hi I am trying to implement Custom authorization using api gateway and lambda. My current understanding is as follows. I have created simple GET method and deployed to Dev Enviroment. Create lambda authorize to return the IAM policy. I used python blue print api-gateway-authorizer-python. Below is the format of response we should get.

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": "execute-api:Invoke",
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:execute-api:us-east-1:{ACCOUNTID}:{APIID}/ESTestInvoke-stage/GET/"
    }
  ]
}
```

In the above IAM policy, Resource is ARN of my Api Dev stage. What is Action indicates? Also to test this now, How can I get token? I want to test it from postman? I am just confused here. I have my AWS account and authorization is nothing but my current account has access to this Dev stage? How internally it works? To store all the permissions do we need to maintain any other DB? Can someone help me to understand this? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a token you need an identity provider. Amazon Cognito is one of those (Google, Facebook works as well). To understand that policy you have to understand the chain of *commands*.

[image]

Suppose a client calls an API endpoint (`GET /orders`), this will trigger a service Lambda so the token can be verified. If the verification is successful, another Lambda (`GetOrder` a business Lambda this time) will be invoked by Api Gateway.

If your service Lambda (Lambda authorizer) will return a policy like this:

```
{
    "principalId": "apigateway.amazonaws.com",
    "policyDocument": {
        "Version": "2012-10-17",
        "Statement": [{
            "Action": "execute-api:Invoke",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:execute-api:{REGION}:{ACCOUNT_ID}:{API_ID}/Prod/GET/"
        }]
    }
}
```

the API Gateway service (i.e. the `principalId` equals to `apigateway.amazonaws.com`) is allowed (i.e. `Effect` equals to `Allow`) to invoke (i.e. `Action` equals to `execute-api:Invoke`) the given API resource (e.g. `Resource` equals to `arn:aws:execute-api:{REGION}:{ACCOUNT_ID}:{API_ID}/Prod/GET/`).

In your case the ARN that you return is related to the tester of API Gateway, but it should point to your real function.

[This](https://medium.com/swlh/how-to-protect-apis-with-jwt-and-api-gateway-lambda-authorizer-1110ff035df1) article may help.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If we need granular level control then how we can do this?

Comment: Your only way is to use custom claims inside the JWT, so you could have a property `role: admin` and at time of evaluation (i.e. when your Lambda Authorizer is running) you can decide if that function (es: `DeleteOrder`) can be invoked by admins. Lambda authorizer get info about the target function inside the event argument.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, what are custom authorisers for API gateway: custom authorisers let you define your own authentication & authorisation logic.

How do you get the token: Thats part of your authentication and authorisation logic, If you are deploying your services on AWS, you can use AWS cognito. API gateway also supports cognito authorization. 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-integrate-with-cognito.html

Using postman to test? it's handy to use postman. I use it.

How does the permission internally work: You can use a token to authenticate a user. (If you are using a JWT token, you can also verify the user's claims).

Do you need an internal db? this is entirely depends on your use case. if your use case is simple as all users treated equal, you might not need a db. lets say some users can access some additional features, you may still not need a db (you can use claims). but if your application becomes complicated and you have to manage different access permissions, users, groups, etc, you may surely need a db.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What is AWS signature in postman? This is used to get tokens as well? Authorization is nothing but Whenever user sends token, that user has access to particular api inside api gate way? But where this mapping will be there? For example, this particular user has access to this particular api?

Comment: if you use `AWS_IAM` on `API Gateway`, then you use `AWS signature` from postman

Comment: Yes if am using Iam. In case of iam how authorisation will work

Comment: if the IAM credentials are valid, the invocation of the endpoint will be succeeded. if you are using lambda, lambda get permissions from its IAM role.